# Why does returning a value the idiomatic way results in a compilation error?

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, iterator, return

I recently broke my head in trying to figure out the root cause of a compilation error with a small snippet of code that i wrote.

Basically, I wrote a generic collection called Tuple and wanted to implement a `std::iter::FromIterator` for the struct. Code below:

```rust
use std::iter::FromIterator;

pub struct Tuple<T>
    where T: Clone {
    pub left: T,
    pub right: T,
}

impl<T> FromIterator<T> for Tuple<T>
    where T: Clone {
    fn from_iter<I: IntoIterator<Item=T>>(iter: I) -> Tuple<T> {
        let mut iterator = iter.into_iter();
        if let Some(left) = iterator.next() {
            if let Some(right) = iterator.next() {
                Tuple {left, right}
            }
        }
        panic!("not enough elements");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1,2,3,4];
    let t = v.into_iter().collect::<Tuple<i32>>();
    println!("{}, {}", t.left, t.right);
}
```

The basic idea is I take the first two elements from the iterator for my Tuple and ignore the rest. If it has less than 2 elements, i panic.

Now i understand this might not be the best way to do it, but I was just prototyping, so bear with me.

I get a compiler error for the above code.

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:15:17
   |
14 | /             if let Some(right) = iterator.next() {
15 | |                 Tuple {left, right}
   | |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found struct `Tuple`
16 | |             }
   | |             -- help: consider using a semicolon here
   | |_____________|
   |               expected this to be `()`
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
              found type `Tuple<T>`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `playground`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

This makes no sense to me, since I say I will return a Tuple in the function signature, and I do return a Tuple, but the compiler expects a void `()` type?

Finally I figured out that by changing the line to a return statement, my error goes away and everything works as expected. i.e. `return Tuple {left, right};` instead of `Tuple {left, right}`

Here is the link to the working version of the code: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e1bddd88b973f724800d57e5b5a0817e)

Can someone explain why? Isn't the no-return keyword method the idiomatic way to return values from a function in rust?

I cannot understand what went wrong. Any guidance is appreciated. Makes me think there is something fundamental i have misunderstood in the language and that worries me.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=04297c9ec4a641b971519cd6516751a0, you need to understand branching logic

Comment: yes that link answers my question! I never knew that. So thanks a lot! Learnt something new today :)

Comment: re https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59584485/can-you-return-a-result-that-works-with-any-possible-error-type?noredirect=1#comment105335742_59584485 — the downvote was only because you hadn't pasted the complete error. Once you had edited that in, the question would no longer be deserving of the downvote.