# Can you return a Result that works with any possible error type?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I want to use multiple libraries that each have their own error types. I don't really care about each specific crate's error type and I want to use the `?` idiom to use the methods of those crates that return a `Result` type.

I don't want to unwrap the values either, that would cause a panic if it hits an error. I might just want to propagate the different errors using `?` to the top and perhaps choose to deal with them or ignore them if I want.

I cannot do that with a `std::result::Result<T, E>` because I don't know the type of error returned (like I said, each crate could return its own errors).

I am aware that in Rust there is no "object-oriented" polymorphism, but there are trait objects. Since a trait object's size cannot be known at compile time, we must hide them behind some kind of pointer like `&` or `Box<_>`.

The base trait implemented by errors seems to be `std::error::Error`.

One thing I've seen is the `fn foo() -> Result<Blah, Box<dyn Error>>` strategy, which utilizes the concept of trait objects.

The problem with this strategy is none of the crates return a boxed error, which leads to the compiler complaining about the same.

An example use-case:

```
use native_tls::TlsConnector; // 0.2.3
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn main() {
    match do_stuff() {
        Ok(string) => {
            println!("{}", string);
        }
        _ => {
            println!("Failed!");
        }
    }
}

fn do_stuff() -> Result<String, Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>> {
    let connector = TlsConnector::new()?;

    let stream = TcpStream::connect("jsonplaceholder.typicode.com:443")?;
    let mut stream = connector.connect("jsonplaceholder.typicode.com", stream)?;

    stream.write_all(b"GET /todos/1 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")?;
    let mut res = vec![];
    stream.read_to_end(&mut res)?;
    String::from_utf8(res)
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=40e91b8fd4c362d41e32b27717417031)

Is there an easy way around this problem? Can I easily abstract away all the different errors and return a `Result` so I can use the `?` idiom?

Comment: Please paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important.

Comment: Really -1? I think i was pretty clear, that the playground link i posted was just an example of the dilemma I am describing. When a function can possible return multiple Error `types` belonging to different crates, how can I abstract them all so that I can just use the `?` idiom and deal with any (different) error type in the calling function instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you return a Result that works with any possible error type?

No, you cannot. On the surface, this cannot make sense. Generic types are *chosen by the caller of the function*, so how would a function create an error that was chosen by someone else, without being told how to construct it?

---

That said, your problem is easily solved. You said:

> so I can use the `?` idiom

If *you do that consistently*, your program compiles:

```
let s = String::from_utf8(res)?;
Ok(s)
```

You could also convert the error type directly:

```
String::from_utf8(res).map_err(Into::into)
```

> none of the crates return a boxed error, which leads to the compiler complaining about the same

It does not for the **5** other cases where you've used `?`, so it's unclear why you make this statement.

Specifically, `Box<dyn Error>` can [be created from any type that implements `Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3CE%3E):

```
impl<'a, E: Error + 'a> From<E> for Box<dyn Error + 'a> {
    fn from(err: E) -> Box<dyn Error + 'a> {
        Box::new(err)
    }
}
```

The `?` operator calls `From::from` for you under the hood.

See also:

- [What is this question mark operator about?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42917566/155423)
- [How to manually return a Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51550167/155423)
- [Rust proper error handling (auto convert from one error type to another with question mark)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48430836/155423)

Comment: But what should the declaration for the calling function be (e.g `do_stuff()` above) to  handle boxed and non-boxed) errors from called functions?